# .htaccess RewriteRule on GoDaddy secondary site

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am having a problem with a GoDaddy hosted site that is not the account's "main" site.  The site's path on the server is: webroot/FBM/

When you access the site, www.mysite.com opens the default file (index.php) located at webroot/FBM/index.php.

Tons of research helped me to find that I needed to use "Options -Multiviews" in the first line of my .htaccess file in order for any RewriteRule to work at all (again, only in a GoDaddy hosted "alternate" site).

Currently, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bonus/(.*)$ /bonus.php?query=%1
```

When I use this .htaccess file,

- www.mysite.com/bonus/ and www.mysite.com/bonus/Stuff works as you would expect (opens /bonus.php with or without the parameter).
- www.mysite.com/bonus.php seems to be working now (I guess something in this current .htaccess file fixed it) but at first it gave a message similar to the message for directly accessing the php file via:
- www.mysite.com/bonus does not work at all but gives a rather odd message:

> The requested URL /FBM/bonus was not found on this server.

Since /FBM is not part of the URL, I would not have expected to see that as part of an error message.

This is a simple use case to display the problem I am having with all of my GoDaddy hosted "alternate" sites.  The other problems are typically much more complex and involve rerouting all calls to the site to index.php. However, for this particular project, I don't need to solve that and I feel that if I can solve this, the answer will be there for the other sites.

By the way, this .htaccess file fails in my development environment (no rewrites to bonus.php, though bonus.php is available directly through the URL).

The whole concept of URL rewriting and regular expressions is foreign to me and reading through google and similar questions on stackoverflow is not helping. I've been researching this problem for several months and I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but I don't like it very much.  I added another line to handle the case where the user doesn't include the trailing slash:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bonus$ /bonus.php
RewriteRule ^bonus/(.*)$ /bonus.php?query=%1
```

I settled for that when this line also didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^bonus/?(.*)$ /bonus.php?query=%1
```

I'm still pretty baffled by the behavior of Apache on GoDaddy for additional hosted domains.

Still welcoming a better answer.